# Comparing Ranges and Pasting Result VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am comparing two ranges from two columns on two worksheets.  Any duplicate data is then written to a third worksheet.  I started with the vba from here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213367.

```
Sub Find_Matches()
Dim CompareRange As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant, CompareRange2 As Variant
Dim MATCH As Range,

Set MATCH = 'this needs to be dynamic and related to x coordinates
Set CompareRange = Workbooks("Test VBA.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10000")
Set CompareRange2 = Workbooks("Test VBA.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10000")

For Each x In CompareRange
If Not IsEmpty(x) Then
For Each y In CompareRange2
If Not IsEmpty(y) Then
If x = y Then MATCH = x 'MATCH currently ends on last x=y value when range assigned
End If
Next y
End If
Next x
End Sub
```

I have tried to take out as much fluff as possible.  The placement on the third blank worksheet should be written to the next cell of a column.  I need help identifying the location of x where x=y in this example.

Thanks in advance!...I've been wrapping my head around this for hours.

Comment: Please indent your code. It's impossible to read when it's all left-aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

10 min later I got it

```
Sub Find_Matches()
Dim CompareRange As Variant, x As Variant, y As Variant, CompareRange2 As Variant
Dim MATCH As Range,
Dim i As Integer

i = 2 'started at 2 to avoid writing over header in A1
Set CompareRange = Workbooks("Test VBA.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A10000")
Set CompareRange2 = Workbooks("Test VBA.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A10000")

For Each x In CompareRange
If Not IsEmpty(x) Then
For Each y In CompareRange2
If Not IsEmpty(y) Then
If x = y Then
Set MATCH = Worksheets(3).Range("A" & i) 'must be set whenever i changes
MATCH = x 'variable is now dynamic
i = 1 + i 'uses next column rather than same coordinates as x
End If
End If
Next y
End If
Next x
End Sub
```